# How to Hide Wordpress Custom Post Meta using Display CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type, display

I'm trying to hide post meta data on our Testimonials posts on our Wordpress site. I placed the following css code in my css file:

.post-meta {display:none !important;}

And it removed the post meta from all posts. However, I ONLY want to hide post meta data from Testimonials (a custom post type). I don't want meta data to be removed from our Blog posts. Is there any way to specify which type(s) of posts to hide meta data? Preferably hoping for an easy CSS solution.

Comment: You can check the page id at the top of the source code. It's unique for each page in a WordPress solution, then use it to select the post meta you want to hide

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to hide post meta on specific types of posts, rather than specific posts. If I were to hide post meta for each page id, I would have to write the same css for each individual post, which is very time consuming and inefficient if there are a lot of posts.

Comment: Oh yeah of course, I misunderstood then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a .body class; a body class will work on all posts. Look in the `<body>` tag of a Testimonial post page for the slug or lowercase name of the Testimonials custom post type (CPT) - there will be many classes, such as `post`, `published`, `logged-in`, etc - and use that to target the .post-meta only on posts/pages with that body tag, i.e.

`body.name-of-custom-post-type .post-meta {display:none !important;}`

If your Testimonial CPT does not show a body class in `<body>`, you can add one with this function in functions.php of your theme:

```
function my_own_body_classes($classes) {

    if ( is_singular( 'Testimonial' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'testimonial-class';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'my_own_body_classes');
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir/Mam. I used "body.testimonial-template-default .post-meta {display:none !important;}" Worked out exactly as you said. :)